# What code checks if LWP::UserAgent is ready to be used?

Tags: perl, perl-module, lwp-useragent

Is there a way I could check that LWP::UserAgent is ready to be used?

It is possible that the reponse `code` of, for instance a `get` request, may always return `500`, and a message in `status_line` may be `500 HTML::Parser object version 3.35 does not match bootstrap parameter 3.72`.

Comment: Can you please post the content of you `@INC` as well as the content of `$HTML::Parser::VERSION` at the point where you are seeing that problem. You can [edit] those into your question.

Comment: Also, can you how you are using LWP::UserAgent? I've altered my HTML::Parser to load a wrong version, but `my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; my $res = $ua->get('http://example.org');` gives me a 200. Are you doing something else? I don't think LWP::UA even uses HTML::Parser. When I try with WWW::Mechanize with the altered HTML::Parser code it will immediately break and throw a whole bunch of errors and compilation stops. **You're not telling us everything**.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your Perl installation is a bit broken. **Retrying the request will not fix it.**

This error message is from XSLoader. [The ExtUtils::MakeMaker toolchain documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker::FAQ#How-do-I-prevent-object-version-X.XX-does-not-match-bootstrap-parameter-Y.YY-errors) explains this:

> XS code is very sensitive to the module version number and will complain if the version number in your Perl module doesn't match. If you change your module's version # without rerunning Makefile.PL the old version number will remain in the Makefile, causing the XS code to be built with the wrong number.

The [XSLoader distribution brings a unit test](https://metacpan.org/source/SAPER/XSLoader-0.24/t/XSLoader.t#L82) to assure that this is happening.

In your message

> 500 HTML::Parser object version 3.35 does not match bootstrap parameter 3.72

it says that your [HTML::Parser](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser) Perl module has version 3.35, but it tries to load an XS library that is version 3.72 (which is the current version). [In line 11 of HTML::Parser](https://v1.metacpan.org/source/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72/Parser.pm#L11) it does `XSLoader::load('HTML::Parser', $VERSION)`, and right above it defined `$VERSION` as 3.72. So that should work.

It's not clear what you're doing exactly, and which modules you are using, but I suggest you reinstall HTML::Parser. I can't say more unless you add more information.

---

I found this by using [grep.cpan.me](http://grep.cpan.me/), which allows you to grep in all files on CPAN. I searched for [*does not match bootstrap parameter*](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=does%20not%20match%20bootstrap%20parameter).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning [grep.cpan.me](http://grep.cpan.me). I was looking for a similar tool.

Comment: I have fixed the problem, but I would like to find a way to check that LWP::UserAgent has all required and correct dependencies. So after I check it I can cozily use LWP::UserAgent->new()->get('http://ya.ru').

Comment: @osiv without knowing exactly what you're doing that's tricky. Usually if a dependency is not there, it should `die`. But yours doesn't. I don't know why not.

Comment: @simbabque, the problem was that HTML::Parser was read from the location defined in $PERL5LIB, but I have removed the HTML directory from the location and now HTML::Parser is read from the buil-in perl directory.

Comment: @osiv that still does not explain why you'd get that as the status line, and why your program doesn't `die` immediately, like mine did when I tried. Or is that HTML::Parser actually on the server end of the request, and the process on the server dies and for some convoluted reason it puts its error message into the status line?

Comment: @simbabque, no I have debugged the program locally and have got the `status_line` value locally.

Comment: @osiv, Re "*I would like to find a way to check that LWP::UserAgent has all required and correct dependencies.*", Really? Because it seems to me you posted a solution that meets your needs in your question.